# Crawling for Eternity

Tags: dynamic, seo, bots, web-crawler

I've recently been building a new web app dealing with Recurring Events. These events can recur on a daily, weekly or monthly basis.

This all is working great. But when I started creating the Event Browser Page (which will be visible to the public internet) a thought came across my mind.

If a crawler hits this page, with a next and previous button to browse the dates, it will just continue forever ? So I opted out of using generic HTML links and used AJAX. Which means that bots will not be able to follow the links.

But this method means I'm losing any that functionality for users without Javascript. Or is the amount of users without Javascript too small to worry ?

Is there a better way to handle this ?

I'm also very interested in how bots like the Google Crawler detects black holes like these and what it does to handle them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `nofollow` tag to the page, or to the individual links you don't want crawled. This can be in `robots.txt` or in the page source. See the [Robots Exclusion Standard](http://www.robotstxt.org/)

You may still need to think about how to fend off ill-behaved bots which do not respect the standard.

Comment: Yes that did cross my mind. But I've still got the issue withe "ill-behaved" bots as you mentioned. And as they keep downloading I keep paying for bandwidth ...

Comment: A common trick is to set up a bot trap -- have some invisible links tagged as `nofollow`, and then set up a rule to drop the TCP packets from any IP address which trips some particular threshold (could be bigger than one, to allow innocent human bystanders to explore a couple of links).

Comment: Ah like that idea. It's great as I could have the calendar crawled then !

Comment: Ended up using this advice. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Even a minimally functional web crawler requires a lot more sophistication than you might imagine, and the situation you describe is not a problem.  Crawlers operate on some variant of a breadth-first search, so even if they do nothing to detect black holes, it's not a big deal.  Another typical feature of web crawlers that helps is that they avoid fetching a lot of pages from the same domain in a short time span, because otherwise they would inadvertently be performing a DOS attack against any site with less bandwidth than the crawler.

Even though it's not strictly necessary for a crawler to detect black holes, a good one might have all sorts of heuristics to avoid wasting time on low-value pages.  For instance, it may choose ignore a pages that don't have a minimum amount of English (or whatever language) text, pages that contain nothing but links, pages that seem to contain binary data, etc.  The heuristics don't have to be perfect because the basic breadth-first nature of the search ensures that no single site can waste too much of the crawler's time, and the sheer size of the web means that even if it misses some "good" pages, there are always plenty of other good pages to be found.  (Of course this is from the perspective of the web crawler; if you own the pages being skipped, it might be more of a problem for you, but companies like Google that run web crawlers are intentionally secretive about the exact details of things like that because they don't want people trying to outguess their heuristics.)

Comment: Thanks you so much for the insight. Used the mentioned solution above so awarded the bounty to it. But would have given it to you both !